# Is my climate map plausible?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, earth-like, weather, currents

I've created an Earthlike planet and spent a lot of time trying to get the climate right. I have included a map of elevation and currents. Are these climates possible, given their surrounding factors? Is there anything that stands out to you?

If the shape is familiar, it's because I used Pangea for inspiration.

[image: Climate]
[image: Elevation and currents]

Comment: For me, there's a very long westward-extending part of Af (rainforest) in the middle, with high mountains halfway there should be enough rain shadow even with prevalent westward winds as depicted, although I'd disagree with wind prevalence here at my first glance. This with Am segment around it IMHO stands out too prominently, it should not be as deep into the land for sure, due to mountains on the way. Given there's a very narrow area of yellow on heightmap at 0 lat oneastern slope, the mountains there should be of volcanic/drift origin, granite and steep, blocking enough rain from the east.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't want the entire west coast to be a desert, would would be the best way to alter the terrain if I wanted more savanna and more rainforest? Would removing part of the mountain/splitting it into two ranges work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the mountain ranges should produce a greater effect on climate.  The high mountain ranges on the west coast have produced BWh zones to their east roughly as expected due to rain shadow, and should have Af, Am, Cf or Df climates on their western slopes, where rising wet air would result in consistent rainfall.

The more central high mountains don't seem to have produced any effect on climate at all, with AF/Am climates to their eastward which should not occur due to the rain shadow caused by the mountains.  I would have expected BW/BS and D climates to the east of the high central mountains.

Moving a little further east, I would also have expected the lower mountain ranges in the north and south to have more effect, promoting Df/Ds climates over them and to their east.

The equatorial islands to the east of the continent would appear to have the correct climate classification.